# How do I publish WordLift's JSON-LD in the page head

Tags: wordpress, json-ld, wordlift

I know that by default WordLift publishes the JSON-LD asynchronously after the page load with an AJAX request and then injects the JSON-LD in the page head.

However I prefer to have the JSON-LD loaded by WordPress synchronously and avoid the AJAX call, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn WordLift's JSON-LD to asynchronous, you can add the following to the theme's functions.php file:

```
// Disable the asynchronous JSON-LD.
add_filter( 'wl_jsonld_enabled', function () {
    return false;
} , 10, 0 );

// Hook to the `wp_head` to output the JSON-LD.
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
    // Check that the Wordlift_Jsonld_Service exists.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Wordlift_Jsonld_Service' ) ) {
        echo '<!-- WordLift JSON-LD service not found. -->';

        return;
    }

    // Determine whether this is the home page or whether we're displaying a single post.
    $is_homepage = is_home() || is_front_page();
    $post_id     = is_singular() ? get_the_ID() : null;

    // Get the JSON-LD.
    $jsonld = json_encode( Wordlift_Jsonld_Service::get_instance()
        ->get_jsonld( $is_homepage, $post_id ) );
    // Finally print the JSON-LD out.
    ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo $jsonld; ?></script>
    <?php
}, 10, 0 );
```